# DevDemon module Tagger with Safecracker

Tags: safecracker

Have an issue with using DevDemons Tagger with Safecracker.
Know this has been working before, so the syntax "should" be right.

Running EE 2.5.5 and TAGGER 3.0.6

The code (I totally stripped all css for testing) looks something like this on the site:

```
{exp:safecracker channel="patricks_blogg" include_jquery="yes"}
<label for="patricks_blogg_tags" class="clearfix">Taggar</label>
{field:patricks_blogg_tags} 
{/exp:safecracker}
```

The error I get is:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'ip_address' in 'where clause'

SELECT `hash` FROM (`exp_security_hashes`) WHERE `ip_address` = '80.217.184.33' AND `date` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-3600 LIMIT 1

Filename: third_party/tagger/libraries/tagger_helper.php

Line Number: 221
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have resolved this error in the most recent update of Tagger. You can download it here:

http://www.devdemon.com/tagger/

Brad

Answer (score 3):

You need to check for an update for Tagger. Looks like maybe you updated to either EE 2.5.4 or 2.5.5. Ellis Lab made some security changes which removed the IP address or moved it. But this caused a number of errors in various Add-Ons.

The last release of [Tagger](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tagger) was before Ellis Lab released the security changes in EE 2.5.4 and EE 2.5.5. From Devot-ee it says [Tagger 3.0.6](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/tagger) was last updated on November 20, 2012. Ellis Lab released [EE 2.5.4 on the 18 Dec 2012](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.5.4-released) (it broke a number of Add-Ons), then they updated to [EE 2.5.5 on 20 December 2012](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.5.5-released) for a date issue.

This means you need to contact [DevDemon](http://www.devdemon.com) and find out if the plan to release a fix for Tagger soon. It's possible if you contact them via their [support form](http://www.devdemon.com/support/) they may send you a new build, that hasn't been officially released. It looks like the did for someone else based on the support forums.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, however I'm running the latest versions on both EE and Tagger (Running EE 2.5.5 and TAGGER 3.0.6) 
Have updated the original post regarding this.

Comment: See my addition to the response.

Comment: Figured, by the nature of your answer that it actually were an incompatibility there, so I've filed a support ticket.
Thanks for the hint in right direction!

Comment: I am not sure if this was EE 2.5.5 or 2.5.4. I never got a chance to install 2.5.4, but this is definitely an EE bug that the add-on develop will have to fix themselves.